# Snackbar is not working in SwipeRefreshLayout on backpress Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

here is my activity_main.xml in xml file root layout was a SwipeRefreshLayout and i implement a snackbar on backpress but show a error called in a id activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout is not supportable then what can i do.

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".CoronaTracker.CoronaTrackerActivity">
<....>
```

and this my java code

```
 boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                return;
            }
    
            this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    
            Snackbar.make(activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout, "Please click BACK again to exit", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
                }
            }, 2000);
```

this line show error

```
Snackbar.make(activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout, "Please click BACK again to exit", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout It is the root layout id of the my activity but stile not working.
```

Answer (score -1):

SnackBar only work with CoordinatorLayout.
try to use CoordinatorLayout as root elemnet

Comment: No bro it working with relativeLayout and LinerLayout but not working with SwipeRefreshLayout.

Comment: make the root view as CoordinatorLayout or relativeLayout or LinerLayout and set the child as RefreshLayout. it work perfectly.